# PHP-getelementsbytagname method not exist in DOMNode class

Tags: php

I readed this [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) document and I found there isn't getelementsbytagname method in DOMNode. But, in my code I can use getelementsbytagname method with DOMNode. Can someone explain me why?

There is my code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.poemjoy.com/show-8-27-1.html');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$articles = $xpath->query('//div[@class="poem_detail"]');

            foreach($articles as $tnode)  
            {
                $ep=$tnode->getElementsByTagName('p');
            }
```

The `$tnode` is DOMNode type variable. I didn't find getelementsbytagname method in the [document](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) I mention before.Why can I use it?

Can someone please explain to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to in your question:

> For clarification:
>
> The assumingly 'discoverd' by previous posters and seemingly
>   undocumented methods (.getElementsByTagName and .getAttribute) on this
>   class (DOMNode) are in fact methods of the class DOMElement, which
>   inherits from DOMNode.
>
> See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

i.e. `$tnode` is a `DOMElement` and not just a `DOMNode`.

The specification of the DOM standard (which PHP implements) describes the permitted node types in a DOM document. These are:

> Document, DocumentType, DocumentFragment, Element, Text, ProcessingInstruction, and Comment
>
> [Source](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodes)

It also notes that these elements are *simply called nodes* meaning that, strictly speaking, there is really no such thing as a `DOMNode` but rather the `DOMNode` is a general term used to talk about any one of those node types.

In your particular case (and as shown in the standard) `getElementsByTagName` is only a member of `Element` and `Document`.

Since your selector is to select `div` *elements* you are actually getting a NodeList of `DOMElement` objects and not `DOMNode` objects and you can use `getElementsByTagName`. However this is dangerous because there is no guarantee that all your results will be `DOMElement` objects, therefore it's good to typecheck before you use the function.